# Using "includes" to return results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a HMT relationship between tab_projects, tab_proj_platforms, and ref_platforms. In my tab_projects.index() I wrote this assignment:

```
@tab_projects = TabProject.includes(:ref_platforms)
```

And I want to return a list of projects along with their associated platforms. The SQL generated was correct and I validated it directly in the database. The record results contained columns from both tab_projects and ref_platforms, which was what I wanted. However my results in @tab_projects only contained the columns in TabProject and nothing from RefPlatform.

I was perusing for potential solutions and it seemed like what I found simply would iterate the collection of `@tab_projects.ref_platforms`, but I am returning everything as a JSON document so I want to collect everything at runtime.

Just in case my model associations contain some bug I've included them below:

tab_project.rb:

```
class TabProject < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tab_proj_platforms
  has_many :ref_platforms, through: :tab_proj_platforms
end
```

tab_proj_platform.rb:

```
class TabProjPlatform < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :tab_project
  belongs_to :ref_platform
end
```

ref_platform.rb:

```
class RefPlatform < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tab_proj_platforms
  has_many :tab_projects, through: :tab_proj_platforms
end
```

How can I save projects and their associated platforms into @tab_projects so I can dump them into a JSON document?

Answer (score 0):

inside tab_project.rb: create scope as follow

```
scope :project_and_platform, lambda { |id_tab_project|
  joins(tab_proj_platform: :ref_platform).select('ref_platforms.*','tab_projects.*').
  where("tab_projects.id = ?", id_tab_project)
}
```

from your TabProject controller, you can access scope as follow

```
@tab_project_with_platforms = TabProject.project_and_platform(params[:id])
```

Comment: I got the following error:

`ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError (Can't join 'TabProject' to association named 'tab_proj_platform'; perhaps you misspelled it?)`

I'm looking up the cause of the error but if you happen to know what is causing that I'd appreciate the correction...

Also since I'm still fairly new to RoR and its features, do you happen to know of a good resource on explaining lambdas in model scopes?

UPDATE: just saw your new post - will keep looking for what names to change.

Comment: I believe yes, since I also have some case almost same with you, just change my code to follow your table names and please be aware for plural and singular inside joins and select

Comment: you can image lambda as  parameters for method

Comment: I think I fixed my spelling errors, but I am now getting some error that's completely different:

`ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1))`

I didn't mention this before (but now it seems to be relevant) but my TabProject model has an HMT relation with TabClientSeat.

My current .index() contains the following:

`@tab_projects = TabProject.project_and_platform().where(:tab_client_seats => {id: params[:tab_client_seat_id]})`

And I checked the value for `params[:tab_client_seat_id]` exists.

Comment: the problem is you called the scope with parenthesis () , remove it as sample below @tab_projects = TabProject.project_and_platform.where(:tab_client_seats => {id: params[:tab_client_seat_id]})